# Home Improvement SE featured on Weekly Podcast Tuesday June 28th at 4pm. Will you listen in?

Tags: discussion

Hope my fellow HI Stack Exchangers will join me on the Podcast next Tuesday 28th June at 4pm.  This should be fun. Home Improvement and DIY will be the featured topic.

Listen live: http://www.livestream.com/stackexchange

SO Podcasts: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/

Comment: Great that you're on the podcast. I'll try to listen as soon as it's posted/I get home from work.

Comment: What timezone is that 4pm in?

Comment: 4pm EDST.........

Comment: @Shirlock - To contact a moderator about a post just click the "flag" link. It doesn't have to be about something bad!

Comment: I'm guessing we have to wait a bit until this gets posted.  Perhaps I'll go back and listen to the older podcasts until then.

Comment: Glad Alex was able to reschedule the DIY podcast for next Tues the 28th.  I had to reschedule due to the tragic death of a close friend and trusted master plumber. Mike was killed and his wife critically injured in a senseless motorcycle accident due to an inattentive auto driver. So sad.

Comment: I hope my friends and other DIY contributors will listen in. If you have any questions or ideas for the SE founders you would like me to relate or discuss on the show, e-mail them to me or post them here.  Podcast is scheduled for 4pm, EDT, Tuesday June 28th. I'll be monitoring this META during the podcast if you want to comment or ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't listened to this episode yet but had to relate the comment from last week's episode for anyone who doesn't listen regularly.  I think it was Jeff Atwood who was saying that they were having shirlock homes from the DIY site on the next show, and he mentioned that he was one of the fairly rare site users that didn't migrate over from the stackoverflow.com programming site.  The producer then chimed in saying something like "just take one look at his profile photo and you can tell he's not a programmer!"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Shirlock couldn't make it - I don't know why - but Jeff & Joel promised that they'd rearrange it, hopefully for next week (7th June).

Comment: I got the impression there were technical difficulties, something to do with Shiba Inu puppies.

Comment: Looks like June 28th is the rescheduled date.